# how do I read sql codes from a .sql file and connect to a database using python

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have below codes to connect to my database with a simple select statement, which works fine. 
However, if I wanted to read from an sql file (say the name is "sqlcodes.sql") and then execute the code to pull data, how do I do that?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sqlalchemy as sqla


def new_connection():
    print('creating new connection')
    return sqla.create_engine(r"mssql+pyodbc://PROD_DSN",echo=False).connect()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    #create DB connection
    conn = new_connection()
    sql = f"select * from Exp.RISK_FACTOR"
    #Read into a DataFrame
    df = pd.read_sql(sql,conn)
```

Comment: Maybe, I do not understand you question correctly but why are you trying to extract data from a database by file-opening instead of connecting to the database and querying?

Comment: the SQL query I want to run is pretty big, as its joining from multiple tables in the database and uses other functions like groupby etc. The example is shown here is a simple select statement (i.e. select * from Exp.RISK_FACTOR).

Comment: Are you trying to do something like this from python:
##not actual code## mydata = pd.read_sql("sqlcodes.sql")

Comment: yeh something similar, as I said the SQL code is is pretty big and I dont want to paste on my python editor. so wanted to know if its could be read from the sqlcode.sql file and then I get my df = pd.read_sql(sql, conn)